# Python valueError using hstack() (ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly)

Tags: python, numpy

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/odroid/trackAndFollow/getPositions.py", line 34, in 
<module>
tfVeloToCamera = np.hstack((np.vstack((rmVeloToCamera, 
zero_array)),np.transpose(translationVector_veloToCamera)))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 
280, in hstack
return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the 
concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Code:

```
rotationVector_veloToCamera = 
np.array([[[-1.77611954,0.30024612,0.76069987]]])
translationVector_veloToCamera = np.array([[ 
0.0146381,0.02553223,0.16231193]])

rmVeloToCamera,jac = cv2.Rodrigues(rotationVector_veloToCamera)
tfVeloToCamera = np.hstack((np.vstack((rmVeloToCamera, 
zero_array)),np.transpose(translationVector_veloToCamera)))
```

I read somewhere that the reason is the shape or dtype.
The shape of the 2 variables inside the hstack is `(4,3) (3,1)`
and both have `dtype=float64`.

Any idea whats causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shapes of the arrays you're trying to stack are `(4, 3)` and `(3, 1)`, then they don't have any matching array dimensions, as `4 != 3` and `3 != 1`. If you were to take the transpose of the first, giving dimensions `(3, 4)` and `(3, 1)`, they should stack.

```
np.hstack((np.zeros((4, 3)), np.zeros((3,1))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

np.hstack((np.zeros((4, 3)).T, np.zeros((3,1))))
Out[56]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

As an aside, you might want to look at shifting over to using `np.concatenate` and specifying an axis, instead of `np.vstack` and `np.hstack`.

Ex:

```
np.concatenate((np.zeros((4, 3)), np.zeros((3,1)).T), axis=0)
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: i transposed the second one and now they are (4,3) and (1,3). according to your explanation this should work since 3=3, but i still get the same error..

Comment: @Drak I could've been clearer; I'll think about how to edit. You're still using `hstack`, which only checks the first axis for a match. `vstack` only checks the second, `dstack` the third. You could use `vstack` or, better, use `stack` and specify `axis=1` as an argument.

Comment: i tried `stack`, it just wont work for me. I made it work with `hstack` and `vstack` (turns out i was missing a `.T`).

could you maybe explain the `numpy.stack` with the different axis= option?

Comment: @Drak because it looks like I was giving the wrong function. `np.concatenate` is the one to go for if the axis being combined on already exists. Edited.