# ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, numpy

l have the following numpy arrays that l want to concatenate using numpy.hstack(())

```
dim(train_frames1)=(2000, 1, 224, 224)
dim(train_frames2)(1000, 1, 224, 224)
dim(train_frames3)=(2000, 1, 224, 224)
dim(train_frames4)=(2000, 1, 224, 224)
dim(train_frames5)=(2000, 1, 224, 224)
dim(train_frames6)=(586, 1, 224, 224)
```

l did the following :

```
import numpy as np
train=np.hstack((train_frames1, train_frames2,train_frames3,train_frames4,train_frames5, train_frames6))
```

l get this error :

```
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989950/numpy-array-concatenate-valueerror-all-the-input-arrays-must-have-same-number) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719424/python-valueerror-using-hstack-valueerror-all-the-input-array-dimensions-exc?rq=1)

Comment: missing assignment operator in second line

Answer (score 1):

solved as follow :

```
train=np.concatenate([train_frames1, train_frames2,train_frames3,train_frames4,train_frames5, train_frames6],axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
import numpy as np 

train_frames1 = (2000, 1, 224, 224)
train_frames2 = (1000, 1, 224, 224)
train_frames3 =  (2000, 1, 224, 224)
train_frames4 = (2000, 1, 224, 224)
train_frames5 =  (2000, 1, 224, 224)
train_frames6 = (586, 1, 224, 224)

train=np.hstack((train_frames1, train_frames2,train_frames3,train_frames4,train_frames5, train_frames6))
print (train)  #your output
```